# What is the Haskell way of solving this?

Tags: haskell

New to Haskell. I have the following code

```
fac :: Integer -> [Integer]
fac x = take 1 $ map (x `mod` ) $ reverse [2 .. xs]
    where xs = floor $ sqrt $ fromIntegral x
```

I want to display the first value from `[2 .. xs]` such that `x mod y == 0`. But I can't use `filter` as that only would work off the output from `mod`. How do I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `filter`. Just compose `(==0)` and `` (x `mod`) `` for the first argument of `filter`.

If you are trying to do Project Euler Problem 3, this will be an incredibly painful way of solving it.

I would suggest the following:

- Define a function for what you have in the `where` clause, i.e. `isqrt = round . sqrt . fromIntegral`
- Define two functions `isPrime` and `primeList` that are mutually recursive for calculating primes and you should use `isqrt` in the definition of `isPrime`, although the use of the `isqrt` isn't actually necessary; I just find it easier to think about for writing this function. (there is a hint below for how to do this step)
- Using `primeList`, define a recursive `factorize` function that outputs a list of primes (or something similar)
- Factorize the number from the question and return the largest prime in the list

What I have suggested above is usually not that great for calculating very large primes quickly, but it should be adequate for this problem. This paper goes into more detail why: http://www.cs.hmc.edu/~oneill/papers/Sieve-JFP.pdf

For future number theory related PE problems, look into using this library: https://hackage.haskell.org/package/arithmoi-0.2.0.4

Other comments:

Instead of `take 1`, you should actually use `head`; it's slightly better.

Also, since the biggest number you will deal with here is 600851475143, you don't actually need the function to have type `Integer -> [Integer]`. 32-bit `Int` doesn't do the trick, because `maxBound :: Int` is 2147483647. `maxBound :: Int64`, however, is 9223372036854775807, which is much more than you need. So you could just define your function to have type `Int64 -> [Int64]` (or just `Int -> [Int]` if the machine is 64-bit already).

Hint:

`primeList` should be defined as something like `primeList = 2 : 3 : filter isPrime [5,7..]`, but you can decide to be as fancy as you want with this); again, these definitions should be mutually recursive.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean by mutually recursive. I get that isPrime would drive primeList. But why should primeList feed back into  isPrime?

Comment: `n` is not prime if some `m` divides `n`. But if `m` divides `n`, then any divisor of `m` also divides `n`. So, in order to determine if `n` is prime, you only need to find out if it's divisible by some prime. Turns out you only need to mod it by primes less than or equal to `sqrt(n)` (if you have not seen this before, trying proving to yourself that this has to be true). If any of the remainders is equal to zero, then `n` is not prime.

Comment: Also, I said `primeList` should be a function in the answer above, but that's not true. `primeList` is just a list, as you have probably already figured out.

Answer (score 2):

> I want to display the first value from [2 .. xs] such that x mod y == 0

In this case, you should not use `reverse`:

```
fac x = take 1 $ filter (\y -> x `mod` y == 0) $ reverse [2 .. xs]
    where xs = floor $ sqrt $ fromIntegral x
```

If you want to find out the first value starting from `xs` such that `mod x y == 0`, there is also no need to use `reverse`:

```
fac x = take 1 $ filter (\y -> x `mod` y == 0) $ [xs, xs-1 .. 2]
    where xs = floor $ sqrt $ fromIntegral x
```

Comment: Just to give additional context, I'm working on problem 3 of Project Euler: What is the largest prime factor of the number 600851475143 ? I'm thinking of using recursion based on this to get to an answer. Would love to know if there's a better way to be approaching this.

Answer (score 1):

```
fac x = take 1 $ filter (\y -> x `mod` y == 0 ) $ reverse [2 .. xs]
    where xs = floor $ sqrt $ fromIntegral x
```

or, to be point-free:

```
fac x = take 1 $ filter ((== 0).(x `mod`)) $ reverse [2 .. xs]
    where xs = floor $ sqrt $ fromIntegral x
```

Not sure if you want `reverse` here, or what exactly is your goal.

Answer (score 1):

You can use filter.  Here's a one-liner (well, two-liner if you count the import):

```
import Data.Ix (range)
fac x = head . filter ((==) 0 . mod x) . curry range 2 . floor . sqrt . fromIntegral $ x
```